# Extract edge of the polygon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, envi

I have Region Of Interest (ROI) files made in ENVI which is made of irregualr shapes of polygon. When I tried to save it in vector file, it showed several lines inside the polygon. What I want is just single line of polygon edge.I would like to extract the edge of the ROI in line using MATLAB. Is there any code that can extract the edge? I have searched in several sites, but failed to find. I assume that there might have some MATLAB code.

Answer (score 0):

the function

```
[in,on] = inpolygon(xq,yq,xv,yv);
```

reference: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html?refresh=true might be what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! I have used contour function instead. I will definitely  use that next time!